# Equality of numbers with specific property

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Here is an problem that bothers me. If you have 11 real numbers with the following property: every 10 of them can be split into 2 groups A and B of 5 numbers, such that the sum of the numbers in group A is equal to the sum of the numbers in group B. Then show that all the numbers are equal.

I can easily solve the problem if the numbers were natural, integers or even rational, but don't have a clue with the real ones. Any idea?

Comment: You probably want to show that all eleven numbers are equal, not necessarily $0$.

Comment: Oh yes that's right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem true even for integers.

Suppose you have seven $1$s and four $3$s.  Then the sum is $19$.

Leave out a $1$ and you have six $1$s and four $3$s. You need $A$ and $B$ to each sum to $9$: try $1+1+1+1+1+1+3$ and $3+3+3$.

Leave out a $3$ and you have seven $1$s and three $3$s. You need $A$ and $B$ to each sum to $8$: try $1+1+1+1+1+3$ and $1+1+3+3$.

Comment: Groups are by 5 numbers sorry I missed it. It is true that way.

Comment: OK - for later readers, this was a response to the question before it was edited

Comment: This is true because you can substract the minimal number from all the numbers and the property preserves. But you get 1 zero between them and it's easy to be seen that you can not have another number different from 0.